# OSRM Extracting - Profile profiles/car.lua not found

Tags: ubuntu, osrm

I am installing OSRM to work on Ubuntu 14.04 Droplet. I am following the tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-osrm-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 and I have reached the point where I need to extract OSRM. I have completed the following steps:

1. Updates and Security
2. Download a Map Export
3. Installed Dependencies
4. Compiled OSRM
5. Configured STXXL

I am currently held back on the Extract the Map step.
[Picture of Instructions from Step 6: Extract Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXt8p.png)

First I run:

ln -s osrm-backend/profiles/car.lua profile.lua
ln -s osrm-backend/profiles/lib

Which seems fine, but then I try:

osrm-extract map.osm

I keep getting this:

[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qhWA.png)

But then I try:
joe@SnakOSRM:~/osrm$ osrm-extract -p profile.lua map.osm
 and get: [Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7f2L.png)

If there is more info I can supply to help me diagnose the situation please let me know! I have a feeling like it could be a directory issue, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere online that will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The last error tells you that your `.osm` file is not a XML file. I would suspect you feed it a PBF file by accident? The correct extension for a PBF file is `.osm.pbf`, we need this to auto-detect the file format.

The guide you linked is outdated with the current OSRM 5.x series.

1. Download a dataset in the `.osm.pbf` format from geofabrik.de
2. We don't require STXXL anymore so you don't need to compile it.
3. Run `osrm-extract map.osm.pbf -p profiles/car.lua`
4. Run `osrm-contract map.osrm`
5. Run `osrm-routed map.osrm` to start the server.
6. The new HTTP API is documented [here](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.10.0/api/#general-options) please note that we now use `lat,lon` as coordinate format.